# Cause of "No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'" bug?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, application, bugs

Distro: Linux Mint 18.2
DE: Cinnamon 3.4.1

I am currently in the middle of trying to figure out whether this bug is apart of the Cinnamon desktop or is a problem with the `Lollypop package`. I sent a bug report to the `Lollypop` developers and the owner replied saying this must be a bug with the applet in cinnamon.

Let me explain the bug before I go further. The bug is apart of the time bar and the 'bring to front' button on the cinnamon sound applet. The time bar doesn't update unless you pause and play the song again, and the 'bring to front' button doesn't work at all.

I decided to go ahead and investigate myself and told the developer that I would be looking at logs and outputs to go ahead and determine if this is really a Cinnamon bug or a application bug. I don't want to make the mistake of sending a bug report to the wrong place.

However, I seem to be stuck. I have looked at the logs and I found errors linking the Sound Applet and Lollypop together, but I don't know much about linux even after being on it for a year, so I have no clue whether or not this is a problem with the sound applet or Lollypop, or even if this is a problem with just my installation. Here are the outputs, found at `~/.xsession-errors`:

```
(process:2856): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:205: unable to sync last running player org.gnome.Lollypop.desktop to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'

(process:2856): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:205: unable to sync last running player org.gnome.Lollypop.desktop to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'

(process:2856): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:205: unable to sync last running player org.gnome.Lollypop.desktop to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'

(process:2856): indicator-sound-WARNING **: accounts-service-access.vala:205: unable to sync last running player org.gnome.Lollypop.desktop to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such interface 'com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound'
```

Could someone please tell me if this is an issue with either: A. The Cinnamon Applet, B. The Application, or C. My installation or need for another package.

And could you please explain how I can tell and if possible, fix this issue?
Sorry if this is the wrong place to put this.